# Unlike Jensen's Inequality, can we upper bound $\log \sum_{i}{u_i \exp(x_i)}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, convex-analysis

According to Jensen's Inequality, it is not hard to derive the lower bound for $\log \sum_{i}{u_i \exp(x_i)}$ due to the convexity of $\log(\cdot)$:

$\log \sum_{i}{u_i \exp(x_i)} \geq \sum_{i}{u_i x_i}$.

However, my question is, can we somehow upper bound the quantity. The idea is that the set $\{x_i\}$ is bounded by $\min x_i$ and $\max_i$ and the second-order derivative of $\log(\cdot)$ is also bounded in the interval $[\min x_i, \max x_i]$. Therefore, we can upper bound it but the question is to what simplicity the bound could be.

I have tried some combinations under some numerical test, and found this bound might work:

$\log \sum_{i}{u_i \exp(x_i)} \leq \sum_{i}{u_i x_i}+\frac{1}{8}\Big(\max x_i\Big)^2$.

But I do not have a way to prove it. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Unless you put some constraints on the $u_i, x_i$ your bound obviously does **not** work: Take $n$ copies with $u_i=1, x_i=-1$ and your bound would imply
$$0 \ge \log \left(\sum_{i}{u_i \exp(x_i)}\right) - \sum_{i}{u_i x_i}
-\frac{1}{8} \Big(\max x_i\Big)^2 = \log(n) -1 + n - \frac{1}{8} $$
which is wrong for all $n>1.$

Comment: @gammatester. Excuse me. I meant $\max_i |x_i|$.  In other words, the infinite norm $||x||_\infty$, where $x = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, there do exists results from mathematical research that give the upper bound. I made some digging on the internet and found the following results. SLAVKO SIMIC [[1]](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/171_07_JIPAM/171_07) shows that for convex mapping $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$, the following bound exists:

$\sum\limits_i{p_i f(x_i)} \leq \sum\limits_i{ f(p_i x_i)}+f(a)+f(b)-f(\frac{a+b}{2})$.

Since $\log(\cdot)$ is a concave function, we should have

$\sum\limits_i{ \log(p_i x_i)} \leq \sum\limits_i{p_i \log(x_i)}+\log(a)+\log(b)+\log(\frac{a+b}{2})$.

Some other upper bounds have also been proposed. For example, in machine learning, Jebara et al. reversed Jensen's inequality for exponential families [[2]](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~jebara/papers/revjenX.pdf).

In fact, I found the previous guess has the correct form. It is not hard to show with SLAVKO SIMIC's result that

$\log(\sum\limits_{i}{p_i \exp(x_i)}) \leq \sum\limits_{i}{p_i\log( \exp(x_i))}+2 ||x||_{\infty}^2$.

Comment: Your links are broken. Correct link to Slavko Simic's paper: http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/105/n099p107.pdf

Comment: $\log(\exp(x_i))$ is just $x_i$

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is some typo in the previous answer.

If  $f(x) = \log(x)$(a concave function)then you will get the upperbound for log sum as:
$$ \log \left(\sum_{i}p_{i} x_{i}\right) \leq \sum_{i} p_{i} \log \left(x_{i}\right) - \log (a)  - \log (b) + 2 \times \log \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$$

By the way, all variable $x_i$ shall vary from a to b.

Moreover, this inequality is not proposed by SLAVKO SIMIC.